# SQLite values being stored as android.widget.EditText@412243c

Tags: android, database, sqlite

So i had a quick question. i am storing the value from an editText into an SQLite database, and then when reading it from the calling page the values are being sotred as android.widged.EditText@412243c. Any idea why this is being stored as opposed to the the string value that was written in the edit text? thanks!

Comment: post relevant part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are fetching your editText's value as follow,

```
String text1 =  editText1.getText();
```

It's wrong way of getting value from EditText, instead you need to use following way,

```
String text1 = editText1.getText().toString();
```